# Contents crawled by the Search Service but dont appears in the search result in Entreprise Search Center Site (SharePoint 2016)

Tags: search, search-results

I added a new content source (pointing at another SharePoint Farm) in the search service.
I performed a full crawl. The process went well with 54 000 successes.

However, whenever I try to search this same contents using the Search Center Site, no result is return.

Do you know what I am doing wrong ?

Regards,

Arioule

Answer (score 0):

Content Sources only define what content to “crawl”.
Result Sources define the subset of content crawled which should be “considered” for searching.

Have you checked your Result Source to see if it’s configured to include content from the other farm?

Edit:  does the user performing the search have permissions in the other farm?

Comment: Hi Greg, I added the content from the other farm as a result source in the search center site. the user performing the search has permissions in the other farm, however I still have the same problem.

Comment: Do any results come back when you “Test” the result source in the dialog where you configured it?

Comment: no result returned

Comment: Unfortunately, your next step is to dive deep into the ULS logs (possibly increasing their verbosity) to see if there are any errors.  :(